# Calling a wcf service in a Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

This could be a really basic question but I haven't figured it out how to call a simple wcf service in a  mvc application.
I add the service reference and in the end I am expecting to call it using the service reference name but in the solution I can't find it!
What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 25/09/2014

1. Create an WcfService App using the existing template Visual Studio 2014
2. Create an MVC 4 Web App using the existing template in Visual Studio 2014
3. Add WcfService reference to the MVC app.
   [image]

Controller code:

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            ServiceReference1.Service1 srv = new ServiceReference1.Service1();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

WCF Service code:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

After adding service reference:

[image]

The error is that ServiceReference1.Service1 srv = new ServiceReference1.Service1(); doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: This is a very broad question. Post your code. What namespace is the service in? Are you importing it?

Comment: I just add a service reference (the wcf service is working fine, I can call it in the browser) with the ServiceReference1 namespace.

Comment: Could you provide your code?  How are you attempting to call it.

Comment: I just create a wcf project (didn't change anything) and then create another project MVC (didn't change anything) and add a service reference of the first one.

Comment: **You still need to follow your ABC's (Address, Binding, and Contract).  So you can actually define / call your endpoints.**

Comment: No one can help you if people can't see what on earth you have so far.

Comment: I updated with code. I noticed I need to add a reference to the wcf service project. In asp.net forms you don't need this... why?

Answer (score 7):

Please try this,

- Right click on 'ServiceReference1' in your MVC project
- Click on 'Configure Service Reference'
- If the field 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' is checked, remove it  (unchecked this field).
- Click Ok button.

Hope It will work,
Thanks.